# MEAN Stack - GET Request Issue for _ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, get

I am experiencing an issue with pulling back data (from MongoLab using NodeJS) for a single data entity (member) in a list of entities (members). I am able to pull back the full list of Members using the following Members Controller and View Members HTML

**Members Controller // Get list of members**

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
Member.find(function (err, members) {
if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
return res.json(200, members);
});
} ;
```

**View Members HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="mem in members ">
{{mem.name}}
{{mem.address}}
{{mem.bday}}
```

Etc.....

When I try and pull back a Single Members (on a different page) using the following Members Controller and View/Edit Member HTML I run into an issue

**Members Controller**

```
exports.show = function(req, res) {
Member.findById(req.params.id, function (err, member) {
if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
return res.json(200, member);
});
} ;
```

**View/Edit Member HTML** has the following

```
<form ng-submit="editMember()" ng-controller="MemberController">
<div class="form-group">
<table class="table table-bordered" width="520" border="1">
Update Member Details for {{member.name}}
```

Etc.

FYI My **Index.js** which contains my routing has the following

```
var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./members.controller');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for this if possible.

Comment: You mention "I run into an issue" - what's the issue? Looks like you are using Angular on the client - correct?

Comment: Thats correct Daniel - The data simply does not appear on the form for the member in question even though the URL specifies the Member_id for that member. I am using AngularJS on the client side yes.